# TableView images from url

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I found a strange problem. I have a JSON web service that returns me:

title
image (link)
featured (bool)
descriprion

I have next code to populate my cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PasakaCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
Pasaka *retrievedPasaka = [allPasakas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = retrievedPasaka.title;
NSString *ImageURL = retrievedPasaka.image;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

Only 4 images are being displayed:

Link that is being displayed:
@".../img/desa.png"

Link that is not displayed:
@".../img/38 papagaiļi.png"

Maybe the problem is in the links? With such symbols as: ļ,ā,ī etc.

And if so, how to resolve this? Because the image names on the server have those symbols in names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that second link contains whitespace. This is incorrect.

Change `ImageURL` initialisation to `NSString *ImageURL = [retrievedPasaka.image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTD8StringEncoding];`

If it does not help take a look into [URL syntax](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt).